# ExtJS 3.4: Grid does not automatically save and restore state. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have an Ext 3.4 grid with stateful:true, a stateId, and each column in the column model has an id.

Yet when I resize columns I don't see any state cookie saved, and the column widths are not restored when the page is reloaded. 
I do have a state Manager with cookie provider defined and I can set/get cookie values via the state manager just fine.

I also added handlers for beforestatesave and statesave and they are being called, but still - no cookie is saved and no state restored. Those handlers are being passed the correct arguments as well - the columns argument show correct updated widths when dumped into the console.

My question is: am I doing something wrong? Should I not expect this to be automatic? 
Do I actually have to use those state events to manually save and restore state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem myself and I figured it out only after about 2 hours of hair pulling.

Do you happen to have a rather large grid?  If the cookie data exceeds 4k, which it will easily do if you have 20+ columns of data, it will not save.  It will not error either.

I suppose the only other option here would be to go to a different state provider.  I'm going to look at the [httpProvider](http://www.extjs.eu/docs/?class=Ext.ux.state.HttpProvider) that [Saki](http://www.extjs.eu) has graciously provided as an alternative.

EDIT:

I've tried to override the provider and remove the string escaping when saving the cookie.  This reduces the size by about 50%.  I cannot seem to consume it when trying to restore though.  I'm certain that the Ext authors were doing this for a reason, otherwise it wouldn't make sense because it inflates the cookie by so much.  So much for a hack.

Answer (score 1):

To make a GridPanel stateful I just added stateful: true to the config and setup my provider right before I create any objects

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({
   expires: new Date(new Date().getTime()+(1000*60*60*24*30)) // 30 days
}));
```

I've not tested if it remembers width but try moving columns and the sort order and see if they are being remembered.

Comment: Yes, I've done all that of course. Width, order, sort - nothing is remembered. The cookie is not even being saved...

Comment: grid have property "statefull:, which being setted to true, means - that grid state is saved.  In fact, myself make js/php generation, so all (sorting, columns, pagination size, filters) was saving & user was able to select one of states from drop down. Its better idea, but more expensive ...